# Mouseover Event for Table Cells

Tags: html, css, cell, mouseover

I know mouseover questions have been asked already but hear me out, my request is little different.  I am trying to set up a table on a Google sites page with the following properties:

1. spanning the entire width of the site
2. clickable (link) cells
3. staggered design
4. cell mouseover - each cell bgcolor changes to white when hovered over

Having a hard time setting #4 with the code I currently have. Help please!  HTML is my 1st preference, CSS is 2nd. I am a beginner so take it a little easy on me!

Comment: Check out this fiddle to get an idea for the look i am going for https://jsfiddle.net/a0xehstz/1/

Comment: you should actually edit your question instead of adding stuff as a comment. Also, there is no #5 on your list.

Comment: I was trying to add the fiddle to the question but it wouldn't let me sorry about that. can you help me @mmgross?

Comment: @DariusH why all your styles are inline? Is there a need for that?

Comment: B/c I am using google sites and it only allows in-line for the html editor. if we can use css i'll gladly accept ur suggestions & just insert it as a gadget @knitevision

Comment: @DariusH does this work? https://jsfiddle.net/a0xehstz/2/

Comment: @knitevision thanks that simple fix did the trick!  One last quick question - Whenever I hover over any element in the table, the outline of the table (a few pixels or so) also acquires a white color.  Any tweaks to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/a0xehstz/4/

I removed outer `tbody` & `tr` & `td`.